# How to delete some rows from database using delete function in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have one table:

```
    CREATE TABLE People 
    (
       id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
       name
    );
```

I wanted to delete some rows from the table by using its id as condition. So I tried to use this one but it was not working at all. So have a look:

```
    //idd is int
    SQLiteDatabase.delete
  (
    "People", 
    "id" + " = ?", 
    new String[]{String.valueOf(idd)}
  );
```

I dont know why it not working. It may because the String and int datatype. I figure it out something and it may work. But it use only two parameters instead of three. And I want to use three instead. So below is what I have figured out:

```
        SQLiteDatabase.delete
      (
        "People", 
        "id" + " = ?" + idd, 
       null
      );
```

So does anyone have any idea and help me out of this problem? I want to delete some rows from my table by using id as whereClause(second parameter) and idd variable which is integer as whereArg(3rd param) with delete function from SQLiteDatabase class.

Answer (score 1):

```
SQLiteDatabase.delete("People", "id = " + idd, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public boolean deleteTitle(Integer idd) 

{

    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, id + "=" + idd, null) > 0;
}
```